# Is there a $httpProvider.interceptor equivalent in android?

Tags: java, android, interceptor

We are developing an android app which interacts with MVC based back end server, the communication between app and server implemented using HttpUrlConnection (get and post methods) is there a way where i can intercept all these request and add extra headers required for authentication at my back end ?

Comment: Have you tried using OkHttp? I suggest avoid every other implementation for http requests.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a higher level abstraction than `HttpUrlConnection` to have this kind of functionality. You can either implement your own wrapper for it, or use an existing REST client library ([REST API Client Library for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13444113/rest-api-client-library-for-android)).